# How to force the Search text field and search button to have exactly the same height

Tags: css, html

I have the following html inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
<form class="customSearch"method="GET" action="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">

<input  class="searchInput  push-up-button" placeholder="Search by tag.." name="searchTerm2" data-autocomplete-source= "@Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Home")" type="text"/><input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn"/>
                            </form>
```

The result will be as follow,

[image]

where the search button and the text field have different height. So how I can force both elements to be on the same horizontal alignment ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try just adding a small margin to the bottom of the button or the top of the search textbox?

Comment: Well technically they seem to have the same height, so you should maybe reformulate your title stating you're looking for vertical alignment instead. And a jsFiddle could also help... maybe during the creation of it you'll realize what is the cause of the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all reset all values for both `input` :

```
input {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
}
```

Then set an equal `height` , `line-height` , `vertical-align` and `box-sizing`:

```
input {
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

After that you can personalize each one with lateral `padding` and color for background and text.

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/3TeHT/6/**